# This office script was running and now shows an error at last line. Any ideas?

Tags: office-scripts

```
    {
  // Get a worksheet named "Template (2)".
  const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Template (2)');

  // Set its name to Date
  let date = new Date(Date.now());
  sheet.setName(`${date.toDateString()}`);
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Line 10: Worksheet setName: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.

Comment: Are you renaming the original Template (2) sheet after you've run the script? Or are you creating a new Template (2) sheet? If you're not doing either of those things, the script will fail after you run it the first time. There will be no Template (2) sheet anymore. It will now have the name of the date you set it to where you call `sheet.setName()`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few rules for worksheet names:

A. You may not name a worksheet using then name of an existing worksheet.

B. Worksheet names may not contain `\` `/` `*` `?` `:` `[` `]` see: https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/what-characters-are-legal-in-a-worksheet-name/

`toDateString` returns something like `Thu Sep 29 2022`. If you run this script twice in the same day (assuming sheet `Template (2)` exists both times and the sheet `Thu Sep 29 2022` is already present) you will get `Worksheet setName: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.`

You can check if the sheet already exists with:

```js
const sheetName = "sheetNameToTest"
const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheetName);
const sheetExists = sheet !== undefined;

if (sheetExists) {
    console.log(`${sheetName} exists!`)
}
```